# What is the most readable regex to extract a second word with no trailing spaces from comma-separated string?

Tags: regex, perl, readability

I have an array of strings of the form:

```
@source = (
     "something,something2,third"
    ,"something,something3   ,third"
    ,"something,something4"
    ,"something,something 5" # Note the space in the middle of the word
);
```

I need a regex which will extract the second of the comma separated words, BUT without the trailing spaces, putting those second words in an array.

```
@expected_result = ("something2","something3","something4","something 5");
```

**What is the most *readable* way of achieving this?**

I have 3 possibilities, neither of which seems optimal readability wise:

1. Pure regex and then capture $1

   ```
   @result = map { (/[^,]+,([^,]*[^, ]) *(,|$)/ )[0] } @source;
   ```
2. Split on commas (this is NOT a CSV so no parsing needed), then trim:

   ```
   @result = map { my @s = split(","), $s[1] =~ s/ *$//; $s[1] } @source;
   ```
3. Put split and trim into nested `map`s

   ```
   @result = map { s/ *$//; $_ } map { (split(","))[1] } @source;
   ```

Which one of these is better? Any other even more readable alternative I'm not thinking of?

Comment: Have you considered using a CSV library?

Comment: Here is another one to question readability: `/(?<=,)([^\s,]+)/` :P

Comment: @Ashley: I think you mean `/(?<=,)([^,]*[^ ,])/`: it's only *trailing* spaces that need to be forbidden.

Comment: @Ashley: I hadn't, but I have now, and my comment stands. `print("abc,def ghi,jkl" =~ /(?<=,)([^\s,]+)/)` prints `def` instead of `def ghi`.

Comment: @ruakh your data does not conform to the user's spec.

Comment: @Ashley - there is no limitation on having spaces in the fields, sorry. They should NOT be removed.

Comment: @WayneConrad - I have. It's not a real CSV, so I can't use any standard ones (e.g. it won't have escaped quotes, etc...). Plus, the thrust of the question is regex rolling by hand - I'm quite familiar with parsing CSVs by CPAN methods :)

Comment: `map { (split /\s*(?:,\s*|$)/)[1] } @source`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [named capture groups](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Capture-groups) and give names to subpatterns with [`(DEFINE)`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#%28DEFINE%29) to greatly improve readability.

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use 5.10.0;  # for named capture buffer and (?&...)

my $second_trimmed_field_pattern = qr/
  (?&FIRST_FIELD) (?&SEP) (?<f2> (?&SECOND_FIELD))

  (?(DEFINE)
    # The separator is a comma preceded by optional whitespace.
    # NOTE: the format simple comma separators, NOT full CSV, so
    # we don't have to worry about processing escapes or quoted
    # fields.
    (?<SEP>  \s* ,)

    # A field stops matching as soon as it sees a separator
    # or end-of-string, so it matches in similar fashion to
    # a pattern with a non-greedy quantifier.
    (?<FIELD> (?: (?! (?&SEP) | $) .)+ )

    # The first field is anchored at start-of-string.
    (?<FIRST_FIELD>  ^  (?&FIELD))

    # The second field looks like any other field. The name
    # captures our intent for its use in the main pattern.
    (?<SECOND_FIELD> (?&FIELD))
  )
/x;
```

In action:

```
my @source = (
     "something,something2,third"
    ,"something,something3   ,third"
    ,"something,something4"
    ,"something,something 5" # Note the space in the middle of the word
);

for (@source) {
  if (/$second_trimmed_field_pattern/) {
    print "[$+{f2}]\n";

    #print "[$1]\n";  # or do it the old-fashioned way
  }
  else {
    chomp;
    print "no match for [$_]\n";
  }
}
```

Output:

```
[something2]
[something3]
[something4]
[something 5]
```

---

You can express it similarly to older perls. Below, I confine the pieces to the lexical scope of a sub to show that they all work together as a unit.

```
sub make_second_trimmed_field_pattern {
  my $sep = qr/
    # The separator is a comma preceded by optional whitespace.
    # NOTE: the format simple comma separators, NOT full CSV, so
    # we don't have to worry about processing escapes or quoted
    # fields.

    \s* ,
  /x;

  my $field = qr/
    # A field stops matching as soon as it sees a separator
    # or end-of-string, so it matches in similar fashion to
    # a pattern with a non-greedy quantifier.
    (?:
        # the next character to be matched is not the
        # beginning of a separator sequence or
        # end-of-string
        (?! $sep | $ )

        # ... so consume it
        .
    )+  # ... as many times as possible
  /x;

  qr/ ^ $field $sep ($field) /x;
}
```

Use it as in

```
my @source = ...;  # same as above

my $second_trimmed_field_pattern = make_second_trimmed_field_pattern;
for (@source) {
  if (/$second_trimmed_field_pattern/) {
    print "[$1]\n";
  }
  else {
    chomp;
    print "no match for [$_]\n";
  }
}
```

Output:

```
$ perl5.8.8 prog
[something2]
[something3]
[something4]
[something 5]
```

Comment: Lovely! Except we are stuck with 5.8 for now. +1!

Answer (score 6):

Of those possibilities, I think #2 is the clearest, though I think I'd adjust it slightly to include the spaces in the `split`:

```
@result = map { my @s = split(/ *(?:,|$)/); $s[1] } @source;
```

(For that matter, I might actually write `/[ ]*(?:,|$)/`, with a no-op character class, just so it's a bit more visible what the `*` is quantifying.)

**Edited to add:** Whoops, I had a stupid mistake before, where this wouldn't remove the trailing space from something like `"foo, bar "`. Now that I've fixed that mistake, the result isn't so nice and simple, and I'm no longer sure if I recommend the above!

Answer (score 1):

I'd have done:

```
my @result = map /,(.*?[^\s,])\s*(?:,|\z)/, @source;
```

Answer (score 0):

Regular expressions are generally not "readable" in the conventional sense. They are more analogous to a complex mathematical formula. If readability is a concern then consider using comments (regex supports embedded comments).

This page provides a good overview: http://www.perl.com/pub/2004/01/16/regexps.html

An example from that page:

```
$_ =~ m/^                         # anchor at beginning of line
          The\ quick\ (\w+)\ fox    # fox adjective
          \ (\w+)\ over             # fox action verb
          \ the\ (\w+) dog          # dog adjective
          (?:                       # whitespace-trimmed comment:
            \s* \# \s*              #   whitespace and comment token
            (.*?)                   #   captured comment text; non-greedy!
            \s*                     #   any trailing whitespace
          )?                        # this is all optional
          $                         # end of line anchor
         /x;                        # allow whitespace
```

Come to think of it, if readability is an issue why the hell are you using perl? ;)

Comment: +1 for using commented regex, though I'd hesitate to accept since your answer doesn't actually shows commented regex I need.

Answer (score 0):

```
@result = map { /,([^,]*?)\s*(?:,|$)/ } @source;
```

Comment: @stackoverflow, OP does not say anything about leading spaces

Answer (score 0):

This is best handled with `split`, which will remove any whitespace preceding the commas for you. Just split on `/\s*(?:,|$)/`, take the second element of the list, and all the hard work is done. The complete code looks like this

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

my @source = (
  "something,something2,third",
  "something,something3   ,third",
  "something,something4",
  "something,something 5  ",
);

my @result = map { (split /\s*(?:,|$)/)[1] } @source;

say "|$_|" for @result;
```

**OUTPUT**

```
|something2|
|something3|
|something4|
|something 5|
```

Comment: @stackoverflow that is intentional. The OP specifically asked for the strings to be presented *without the trailing spaces*.

Answer (score 0):

I like your option 3 best. 
It clearly identifies the different steps you are taking to 'select' the right data and what extra manipulations you then do on it.

So if the criteria is 'readability': option 3 is the clear winner.